# Write in a file a fixed interval in Android

Tags: android, timertask

I have a question regarding writing into a file at a regular interval in Android. What I want is to log into a file some data into a file which is located in /sdcard/ at an interval of 500ms. How  I can do this using the TimerTask class?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Service that runs as long as your application is running. You can find out more about Services here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Be sure you stop the service when the app shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use a Service, although that is certainly an option.

You could just start up a Handler when your app starts.

```
// Declare global vars ->
Handler runner = new Handler();
Runnable doLog = new Runnable(){

    public void run(){

        writeLog();
        runner.postDelayed( this, 500 );
    }
};

// In onCreate ->
runner.postDelayed( doLog, 500 );
```

Comment: Just declare a variable like `int stopAt = 10000` and `int msRunning;`. Then in `run()` you can add 500ms to `msRunning` and check if `msRunning >= stopAt`

Comment: As for appending the log, I don't know much about external logging (never done it). But as a _temporary_ fix you could just hold your log string in a variable, appending to that whenever you log something and then just write the whole string into the file when you `writeLog()`